# Knowing a file was accessed IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I need to be able to know when a file is accessed on an IIS server. In other words, I have a folder where a bunch of files are placed for users to download. Is there a way for me to know when one of these files is accessed? I am using C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always parse the IIS logs to find out when a file was accessed, by whom (within limits), and how long the transfer took.

Alternatively, you could write an HttpModule or HttpHandler that would handle the file download calls, and log it on access.

Going the HttpModule route, it could be injected now without worrying about changing the links to the files themselves.  A HttpHandler would require changing the links to the files.

Regardless utilizing IIS logging, as suggested by @john saunders in the comments is probably the best bet.  You can tell IIS to log to store the logging information in a database then run sql queries against that logging table to show real time accesses.

Comment: Using custom logging or database logging, he wouldn't have to parse.

Comment: I would prefer if this was in real-time, versus parsing the IIS logs. Can you suggest any resources on ow to write an HTTPHandler? I don't have much experience with this.

Comment: True, but custom logging always has a chance of missing something. IIS logs are reliable because the web server generates them, not the application that runs on it.

Comment: @Michael: I mean configuring IIS for custom logging, not using a separate application.

Comment: @Steve: an HttpHandler wouldn't help. You would need an HttpModule.

Comment: @John: Will an HttpModule be as acurate as parsing the log files? Is it difficult to implement?

Comment: @Steve: you would create an HttpModule which would see every request for one of these files. It would be part of the IIS pipeline for accessing the file. They are not difficult to create.

Comment: @John: Perhaps I should have mentionned, the files being accessed are not ASPX files rather they are static files. Will HttpModules fire in this case?

Comment: @Steve: yes, they will, if you configure IIS correctly. Which version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

IIS log parsing is the way to go here. And with the [IIS log parser](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1976) it is disturbingly easy. You could also use most of the old-style offline web log parsers if you needed decent reporting on this.